# No value Given for one or more parameter

Tags: sql, vb.net

```
Public Sub fillproductinfo(ByVal Productid As String)
    ProductsTA.FillByProductID(ProductDataset.Products, Productid)
End Sub

If DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
End If


Dim productid = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value
EditProduct.fillproductinfo(productid)


Dim EditProductwindow As New EditProduct
If EditProduct.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    ProductsTableAdapter1.Fill(MyDataset.Products)
End If
```

In my Database The actual column name was `Product ID`, when I made a query using SQL statement I put this condition "`where ProductID = ?`"

Comment: First, do not post images of your code. Copy and paste it as text in your question. Second. Post the code relevant to your problem, the call that fails tell us nothing, you should post the called code and possibly describe the structure of your database table

Answer (score 0):

When asking a question like this one you would be better off showing your SQL statements along with code which shows flow e.g. in your example you have parts of code outside of procedures/functions/events while you should show said code in their containers e.g. procedures/functions/events.

Below I'm using the Product table from Microsoft NorthWind database. One query is used to get all data, another get data (one record) by primary key and the last one to get a list of products which you seem not to need but here to be complete as I would not want a user to type in a invalid id or name and this can be complimented with a auto-complete combo box. I've comments each section of code so you can follow along.

Images
DataSet (.xsd)
https://1drv.ms/i/s!AtGAgKKpqdWjiGseXZ9FLOr1mMvZ
Form 
https://1drv.ms/i/s!AtGAgKKpqdWjiGzfO22-jdRb-eAs

Form code

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub ProductsBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
        Handles ProductsBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
        Me.Validate()
        Me.ProductsBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.DemoDataSet)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' disable constraints as the query to get product name and id violate relational
        ' rules in the database setup in Microsoft NorthWind database
        Me.DemoDataSet.EnforceConstraints = False
        ' FillByProductList is a subset of data e.g. id and name of product
        Me.ProductsTableAdapter.FillByProductList(Me.DemoDataSet.Products)
        ' create a list containing id and name of products for combo box
        Dim ProdList As List(Of Product) =
            Me.DemoDataSet.Products _
            .AsEnumerable _
            .Select(Function(row) New Product With
                {
                    .Id = row.Field(Of Integer)("ProductId"),
                    .Name = row.Field(Of String)("ProductName")}) _
            .ToList
        ' insert a select all
        ProdList.Insert(0, New Product With {.Id = 0, .Name = "All"})
        cboProducts.DataSource = ProdList
        cboProducts.DisplayMember = "Name"
        cboProducts.ValueMember = "id"
        ' clear so that we can set Constraints back on
        Me.DemoDataSet.Products.Clear()
        Me.DemoDataSet.EnforceConstraints = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdGet_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdGet.Click
        Dim primaryKey As Integer = CInt(cboProducts.SelectedValue)
        If primaryKey = 0 Then
            Me.ProductsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DemoDataSet.Products)
        Else
            Me.ProductsTableAdapter.FillByPrimaryKey(Me.DemoDataSet.Products, primaryKey)
        End If
    End Sub
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Demo to get current DataGridView primary key for use in a data operation
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender"></param>
    ''' <param name="e"></param>
    Private Sub cmdCurrentRowKey_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If ProductsBindingSource.Current IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim primaryKey As Integer = CInt(CType(ProductsBindingSource.Current, DataRowView).Item("ProductId"))
            MessageBox.Show($"Current row primary key is {primaryKey}")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
''' <summary>
''' Class for ComboBox.
''' Recommend this class be in it's own physical
''' file, placed here for demo purposes only.
''' </summary>
Public Class Product
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
End Class
```

So your code may look proper (other than obtaining the key value from the DataGridView rather than the data source) yet the error message does tell you that the primary key is net be set in the where condition so why not post your query or simply review what I posted and mimic that in a edited version of your question.

Bottom line is when asking questions here be specific and not lackadaisical which indicates you are not serious in learning how to correct the issue at hand.

The people here are well versed in these issues and my guess is less will respond from how you worded your question. So take time to edit your post.